# IIS hosted site is not accessible from another machine in same domain

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I have hosted an ASP.Net site in IIS 7.5.
I am able to access it using with full qualified path.

https:// macihnename(or IP Address) (or localhost)/AppName/pages.aspx

When I try same from other box of same domain it dose not show any page.
However I am still able to open default IIS page of server box.

can anyone think of what I'm missing ?

Comment: Can you ping each machine from the other?

Comment: Server 2008?  Windows firewall has port 80 open?